# One component somehow rendered everywhere in all urls

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner of react js

In my index.js I mapped different url to different component

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/signInSignUp" component={SignInSignUp} />
            <Route path="/questions" component={questions} />
            <Route path="/cookieTest" component={cookieTest} />
            <Route path="/timeSlotFormTest" component={timeSlotFormTest} />
            <Route Path="/QuestionTest" component={QuestionTest} />
            <Route path='/ScreenBlockerTest' component={ScreenBlockerTest}/>
        </div>

    </BrowserRouter>
```

I guess it doesn't matter how I named them. The problem is component "QuestionTest" is being rendered in all url, even those url I didn't define like "localhostL:xxx/hahahahahaha"will also render "QuestionTest" component

Is it because some js is cached?

I do appreciate any help! This thing is driving me crazy

Comment: Are you using React.js with ASP.Net Core or something similar? I ask because it seems like you have a redirect somewhere and that will help determine where that could be. Otherwise I would expect 404 error if you're trying to browse to a resource that doesn't exist.

Comment: I use react js as front end and node js express as back end. I don't have a framework to connect them... react js is using "pure" fetch to get data

Comment: Now you mention it, my server does send 302 code sometimes...But I modified them as they are not doing so anymore. Do you know how to remove the cache in broswer? thank you!

Comment: And actually it is not being redirected.
When you render an existing url, it will render both the original component and that "QuestionsTest" component

Comment: Ah, interesting. As far as clearing cache is concerned with Firefox you can hit ctrl+shift+del to open the data management window, or just browse through the settings for privacy and the clear data option.

Comment: Becuase Path="/QuestionTest" props start with capital letter. So if there is no path prop, this route match to any of URL.

Comment: Also if path will match to more then one route, the all of them will be displayed. Do prevent it please consider using Switch component https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md - then first of matched component will be displayed.

Comment: I changed the url case... I don't think it is working

Comment: Consider wrapping your routes in a `<Switch></Switch>` component.